# xsl muenchian grouping multiple levels

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

I have been trying to learn using other posts to understand muenchian grouping but am struggling to get the right grouping into a table format.The grouping needs to be two levels, firstly by the sport season 'Years' and then within each season show the matches grouped by 'Group'. I've managed to group the 'Group' but they are all showing under the latest season rather than splitting into the respective seasons. Here is an example of the xml:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <QueryResults>
    <Years>2013/2014</Years>
    <Group>1</Group>
    <TeamNameShort>TeamA</TeamNameShort>
  </QueryResults>
  <QueryResults>
    <Years>2013/2014</Years>
    <Group>1</Group>
    <TeamNameShort>TeamB</TeamNameShort> 
  </QueryResults>
  <QueryResults>
    <Years>2013/2014</Years>
    <Group>2</Group>
    <TeamNameShort>TeamC</TeamNameShort>
</QueryResults>
<QueryResults>
    <Years>2013/2014</Years>
    <Group>2</Group>
    <TeamNameShort>TeamD</TeamNameShort>
</QueryResults>
 <QueryResults>
    <Years>2012/2013</Years>
    <Group>1</Group>
    <TeamNameShort>TeamA</TeamNameShort>
</QueryResults>
<QueryResults>
    <Years>2012/2013</Years>
    <Group>1</Group>
    <TeamNameShort>TeamB</TeamNameShort>
  </QueryResults>
  <QueryResults>
    <Years>2012/2013</Years>
    <Group>2</Group>
    <TeamNameShort>TeamC</TeamNameShort>
  </QueryResults>
  <QueryResults>
  <Years>2012/2013</Years>
  <Group>2</Group>
  <TeamNameShort>TeamD</TeamNameShort>
  </QueryResults>
</DocumentElement>
```

and the xsl currently looks like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:cfg="http://tempuri.org/config"
exclude-result-prefixes="cfg"
> 

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<!-- index by season -->
<xsl:key 
name="Season"  
match="QueryResults" 
use="Years" 
/>

<!-- index by "Pool"  -->
<xsl:key 
name="Pool" 
match="QueryResults" 
use="Group" 
/>

<xsl:template match="DocumentElement">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- group by season -->
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="season" select="
    QueryResults[
      generate-id()
      =
      generate-id(key('Season', Years)[1])
    ]
  ">
    <xsl:sort select="Years" order="descending" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Season -->
<xsl:template match="QueryResults" mode="season">
<xsl:variable name="y" select="Years" />
  <table>
    <tbody>   
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Season <xsl:value-of select="$y"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Pos</th>
        <th>Group/Year</th>
        <th>Team</th>
    </tr>

<!-- group Season by Pool -->
<xsl:apply-templates mode="pool" select="
    key('Season', $y)[
      generate-id() 
      =
      generate-id(key('Pool',Group)[1])
    ]
  ">
</xsl:apply-templates>
</tbody>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Pool -->
<xsl:template match="QueryResults" mode="pool">
<xsl:variable name="g" select="Group" />

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Pool <xsl:value-of select="Group"/></td>
  </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="key('Pool',$g)"> 
    <tr>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="Group"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="Years"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="TeamNameShort"/></td>
    </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="QueryResults">
<xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you should not be grouping just by the **Group** element, but by **Group** for a given **Year**. In practical terms you need to use a concatenated key

```
<xsl:key name="Pool" match="QueryResults" use="concat(Years, '|', Group)"/>
```

Then it is simply a case of using this concatenated value wherever you refer to the key. For example

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="pool" select="
   key('Season', $y)
      [
         generate-id() = generate-id(key('Pool',concat(Years, '|', Group))[1])
      ]"/>
```

Note the `|` character here can be anything really, just as long as it doesn't appear in either of the two values you are concatenating.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cfg="http://tempuri.org/config" exclude-result-prefixes="cfg">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/><!-- index by season -->
   <xsl:key name="Season" match="QueryResults" use="Years"/><!-- index by "Pool"  -->
   <xsl:key name="Pool" match="QueryResults" use="concat(Years, '|', Group)"/>

   <xsl:template match="DocumentElement">
      <xsl:copy><!-- group by season -->
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="season" select="QueryResults[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Season', Years)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="Years" order="descending"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template><!-- Season -->
   <xsl:template match="QueryResults" mode="season">

      <xsl:variable name="y" select="Years"/>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="3">Season 
                  <xsl:value-of select="$y"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th>Pos</th>
               <th>Group/Year</th>
               <th>Team</th>
            </tr><!-- group Season by Pool -->
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="pool" select="key('Season', $y)[generate-id()  = generate-id(key('Pool',concat(Years, '|', Group))[1])]"/>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Pool -->
   <xsl:template match="QueryResults" mode="pool">
      <xsl:variable name="g" select="concat(Years, '|', Group)"/>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3">Pool 
            <xsl:value-of select="Group"/></td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('Pool',$g)">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="Group"/>
            </td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="Years"/>
            </td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="TeamNameShort"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="QueryResults">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, great solution - thank you!

Comment: This is an elegant solution, well written up. Nice job!